# How to load a value into a neon s-register?

Tags: assembly, arm, neon

I want to optimize our assembler algorithm by doing multiple operations and once. This can be done by using vectors of the neon module in arm assembler.

I'm trying to add one vector (2x32bit) to another.
If I understood it correctly, d0 constists of s0 and s1.
I want to load one value into s0 and another one into s1.
So I can add s0 and s1 and the same time to s2 and s3 (of d1).

```
VADD.I32    d1, d0
```

But to do that, I first have to load data into d1 and d0.
I tried

```
VMOV    s0, d5
```

and

```
VMOV    d0[0], d5
```

but both of them throw errors while compiling.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you working with floating points?

Comment: @InfinitelyManic Nope, with unsigned integer (32 bit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@michidk Since Sx registers may be paired with Dx registers; e.g., {S0, S1} = D0. You would generally move Dm to Dd or do something like vmov d1, d2 since I don't think you can move Dx to Sx.

So let's place some values into s1 and s1, respectively.

```
movw r1, #0x123
movw r2, #0xabc
vmov s1, r1             // s1 in this case is d0.u32[1]
vmov s2, r2             // s2 in this case is d1.u32[0]

vorr d1, d0             //
```

...

GDB shows that the raw values are indeed present. Further, you see that the values are viable from the unsigned 32-bit portions of D0 & D1.

```
(gdb) info register all 
s1             4.07777853e-43   (raw 0x00000123)
s2             3.85076818e-42   (raw 0x00000abc)

(gdb) p/x $d0.u32
$24 = {0x0, 0x123}

(gdb) p/x $d1.u32
$25 = {0xabc, 0x0}
```

With the instruction "vorr d1, d0", we copy d0.u32[1] into d1.u32[1] which is s3; without disturbing d1.u32[0] which is s2.  So in this sense we move part of D0 to S3.

```
(gdb) p/x $d1.u32
$28 = {0xabc, 0x123}

(geb) info register s3
s3             4.07777853e-43   (raw 0x00000123)
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about vorr.. is there also a way to copy the first part instead of the second of a d-register?

Comment: @michidk Well, if you are going to use vorr then dx.u32[0] & dx.u32[1] are going to have values. This is why using a debugger is valuable. Is this a class assignment?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to check assembler, processor documentation for your target machine. This crude example runs on Cortex-A9 Marvell PJ4Bv7 by Scaleway.

```
movw r0, #0xc0de
movw r1, #0xdead
vmov s0, s1, r0, r1

movw r0, #0xf00d
movw r1, #0xbaad
vmov s2, s3, r0, r1


(gdb) i r a 
d0             1.2096437008836935e-309  (raw 0x0000dead0000c0de)
d1             1.0140805688480121e-309  (raw 0x0000baad0000f00d)
```

Edit:
You could also load values into, let's say, d0 from memory:

```
array: .byte 3,1,4,1,5,9,2,6,5,3,5,9
...
ldr r0,=array
vldr d0, [r0]
```

GDB results for the 8 unsigned byte size integers in D0

```
(gdb) print $d0.u8
$8 = {3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6}
```

Comment: I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3 (ARM Cortex-A53). How did you debug/output the values of those registers?
So I have to load the values in thumb registers first? So to load them from a d-register, I have to load them into an thumb register first and then back into s-registers? There must be an more efficient way?
What would I do if I want to load s2, into s6?

Comment: @michidk Debug was done using GNU Debugger GDB. What tools are you using?

Comment: @michidk Check out  https://people.xiph.org/~tterribe/daala/neon_tutorial.pdf for reference. I cannot login to ARM.com at the moment

Comment: I was just using the gcc compiler and printf. I already now this tutorial (and nearly all resources I could find online) didn't answer my question though. I think its not possible to load something directly into one single s-register... Thanks for your help!

Comment: @michidk What do you want to load or move directly into s0; an immediate or something from memory?  Did you try vmov s2, s3, r0, r1?

Comment: I want to move a value stored in a d-register into an s-register.